# What does p[k] = A[k, k+1] mean in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

So A is a 2D matrix as `A = np.zeroes((n, n+1))`
and `p = np.zeros(n)`

now on running a loop

```
for k in range(0,n):
    p[k] = A[k,k+1]
    return p
```

so what does `p[k] = A[k,k+1]` mean?

Comment: @RachitSingh, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Indexing lists, arrays, and matrices is covered _very well_ by other tutorials, and Stack Overflow is not a tutorial website. Since your question is so basic, you might find it more useful to go through a tutorial that explains a bunch of related concepts well instead of asking a specific question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loops over your matrix `A` and assigns a specific values to array `p`. Note that the ability to index a numpy array via a tuple like this does not extend to native python arrays or lists.

```
import numpy as np

n = 2
p = np.zeros(n)
A = np.zeros((n, n+1))

# lets add some clarity
A = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

for k in range(0, n):
    print("The value of A[k, k+1] is %s and A[k][k+1] is also %s" % (A[k, k+1], A[k][k+1]))
    p[k] = A[k, k+1]

print("That results in P being: %s" % p)
```

Would give you:

```
The value of A[k, k+1] is 2 and A[k][k+1] is also 2
The value of A[k, k+1] is 9 and A[k][k+1] is also 9
That results in P being: [2. 9.]
```